# NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy for integral contain Bessel function of first kind

Tags: numerical-integration

I am new in Mathematica, I try to find the following numerical integral.
but I get the error message ( NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy ...),  I know that there is a divergence since there is a rho in the denominator of the fraction but how can I solve that?I think I should transform the integral any help? can any one transform the integral for me

```
NIntegrate[ρ*Replace[f[5], 
   f[l_] :> {0, ((155*2)/ρ)*
       Integrate[
        BesselJ[l, 23*y]^2*y, {y, 0, ρ}], (6.75*2*l*
         Integrate[BesselJ[l, 23*y]^2/y, {y, ρ, Infinity}])/
       10^2} . 
           {0, -D[(6.75*2*l*
           Integrate[BesselJ[l, 23*y]^2/y, {y, ρ, Infinity}])/
         10^2, ρ], (1/ρ)*
       D[ρ*(((155*2)/ρ)*
           Integrate[
            BesselJ[l, 23*y]^2*y, {y, 
             0, ρ}]), ρ]}], {ρ, 0, Infinity}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

Comment: Please edit your question: prior to copy and paste, convert your cell to `InputForm` (or `Raw InputForm`)

Comment: How I edit that?

Comment: Click on the word Edit below the question

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** The expression provided by OP can be cleaned up a bit. For example, this is a subexpression of the expression provided by OP, with the exception that I put an `Inactive` in to get Mathematica to exploit the fact that there is derivative `D` just outside:

```
D[ρ*(((155*2)/ρ)*Inactive[Integrate][BesselJ[l,23*y]^2*y,{y,0,ρ}]),ρ]
```

This simplifies to

```
310*ρ*BesselJ[l,23*ρ]^2
```

**Step 2.** Doing Step 1 for the entire integrand that OP has provided, I get the following simpler formula for the integrand, where I also replaced `41.85` by `4185/100` to avoid problems with floating point numbers:

```
integrand[l_]:=integrand[l]=Assuming[ρ>0, 4185/100 l BesselJ[l, 23 ρ]^2 (
    ρ^2 Integrate[BesselJ[l, 23 y]^2/y, {y, ρ, \[Infinity]}]
    + Integrate[y BesselJ[l, 23 y]^2, {y, 0, ρ}])/ρ//Simplify];
```

This can be evaluated. For example, taking the value `l==5` in the question:

```
integrand[5]
(* (1/(1566219705620 ρ^7))837 (529 ρ^2 (-4608 + 
      101568 ρ^2 - 5596820 ρ^4 + 
      740179445 ρ^6) BesselJ[0, 23 ρ]^2 - 
   23 ρ (-18432 + 1625088 ρ^2 - 22387280 ρ^4 + 
      740179445 ρ^6) BesselJ[0, 23 ρ] BesselJ[1, 
     23 ρ] + (-18432 + 2843904 ρ^2 - 102981488 ρ^4 - 
      2960717780 ρ^6 + 391554926405 ρ^8) BesselJ[1, 
     23 ρ]^2) BesselJ[5, 23 ρ]^2 *)
```

**Step 3.** Let us plot this:

```
Plot[integrand[5],{ρ,0,5},PlotRange->All]
```

This gives

[image]

Looks nice, but decay seems slow. In fact, let us also plot `ρ` times the integrand:

```
Plot[integrand[5]*ρ,{ρ,0,5},PlotRange->All]
```

This gives

[image]

It seems likely that this oscillates forever with some fixed amplitude (see remark below). Thus `integrand[5]` is `1/ρ` times this oscillation. That is [too slow for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Definition_and_divergence) of the integral over `{ρ,0,\[Infinity]}`. Hence the integral does in fact not converge, it is $+\infty$.

The divergence is not due to the behavior near `ρ==0`, in fact the integrand decays quickly towards `ρ==0`. Rather, the divergence is due to slow decay as `ρ` goes to infinity.

**Remark.** The `1/ρ` decay is due to the following terms in `integrand[5]//Expand`:

```
  ρ BesselJ[0, 23 ρ]^2 BesselJ[5, 23 ρ]^2
  ρ BesselJ[1, 23 ρ]^2 BesselJ[5, 23 ρ]^2
```

Comment: following your step, I get this result in step 2 (Assuming[\[Rho] > 
  0, {0, (310/\[Rho])*
    Integrate[
     BesselJ[l, 23*y]^2*y, {y, 0, \[Rho]}], ((675/100)*2*l*
      Integrate[BesselJ[l, 23*y]^2/y, {y, \[Rho], Infinity}])/10^2} . 
     {0, (0.135*l*BesselJ[l, 23*\[Rho]]^2)/\[Rho], 
   310*BesselJ[l, 23*\[Rho]]^2}]).